# Getting Data from Public Google Calendars with Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api

I want to download and parse all the event data from a website's public google calendar, what would be the best way to do so? I'm considering just downloading the ics file or getting xml data and parsing that myself. I've looked into google api but it looks unnecessarily complex if all I want to do is read the data.  I'm a beginner to working with API's and programming in general so I'm having trouble navigating all that documentation. They don't provide very many helpful examples.

Comment: Could you provide a link to such a calendar?

Comment: The  ics file can be read with the [icalendar-gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/icalendar).

Comment: I'm trying to read the calendar from here: http://www.ocs.fas.harvard.edu/students/undergrad-events.htm

I guess the google API would probably be the most useful, but how would I get started with that?

Comment: What code have you written? We expect you to have tried to come up with a solution, before you ask.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this:

```
require 'ri_cal'
require 'open-uri'

components = nil
open("https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/ocs.events%40gmail.com/public/basic.ics") do |cal|
  components = RiCal.parse(cal)
end

components.each do |calendar|

  calendar.events.each do |event|
    puts "#{event.summary} starts at: #{event.dtstart} and ends at #{event.dtend}"
  end

end
```

You will need to install the ri_gem.

UPDATE: Using iCalendar

```
require 'icalendar'
require 'open-uri'

calendars = nil
open("https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/ocs.events%40gmail.com/public/basic.ics") do |cal|
  #calendars = RiCal.parse(cal)
  calendars = Icalendar.parse(cal)
end

calendars.each do |calendar|

  calendar.events.each do |event|
    puts "#{event.summary} starts at: #{event.dtstart} and ends at #{event.dtend}"
  end

end
```

Comment: Do you guys recommend ri_cal or the icalender gem? If there's an appreciable difference

Comment: To be honest, I was interested in how to do what you asked for, search for Ruby ical gem which led me to a stack overflow comment that someone thought ri_cal was the best then hit the ri_cal rubydoc http://ri-cal.rubyforge.org/rdoc/ to create the program above. Given that it was that simple I guess my preference would be for ri_cal :-)

Comment: Ah I see, yeah I saw that same comment but it was also a few years old and I think icalendar has made some updates since then.

Comment: Looking at iCalendar the interface is exactly the same. I'll update my answer

Comment: Well it seems like 5 hours ahead of eastern time would be london time. So is this a standard for ical files or just for computers in general to record time in terms of the london time?

Comment: Answering my own question: Yes, it's in london time unless the time zone is specified, which is what the trailing '+00:00' means. '-05:00' would imply eastern time.

Comment: Just saw this. FYI, I think 'London Time' is more correctly referred to as UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). Anyway, looks like you got it. Hope you were able to use the code above to do what you want.

Comment: Hi redcup, do you think the answer I gave is the correct one or are you looking for something else? Cheers